# ImageView rotate + fill screen

Tags: java, android, layout, rotation

I would like to fill the screen with a rotated ImageView. The question of how to fill the screen with an ImageView and how to rotate an ImageView has been answered seperately mutlipe times on the site. My XML code looks as follows.

```xml
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/video_frame"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"
  android:rotation="270"
/>
```

The problem is that the rotation happens after the image has been fitted with no rotation applied and I end up with an image that does not fill the screen.

I could of course just rotate the images (and remove the ImageView rotation) as follows:

```java
 Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
 mMatrix.postRotate(-90);
 ImageView video = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.video_frame);
 Bitmap frame = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("path/to/file.jpg");
 Bitmap frame2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(frame, 0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), mMatrix, true);
 video.setImageBitmap(frame2);
```

Here the problem is that the application is realtime and I am serving multipe frames per second (20+). The rotation per frame seems to be quite heavy and even if in this case the images fill the screen, the result is lagging and not as responsive as without the matrix rotation.

My question would therefore be if I could solve this issue with XML only or in any other way without rotating every image I want to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RotateLayout`  and put your ImageView in `RotateLayout` and pass your rotation in `setAngle()` method of  `RotateLayout`, So It rotates only view not Image or we can say `bitmap` it's much faster than any other rotation of Images.

you can add its dependency in Gradle file.

Usage

In your layout file add

```
<com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:angle="90"> <!-- Specify rotate angle here -->

    <YourLayoutHere
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </YourLayoutHere>
</com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout>
```

Voila! Your layout will be rotated 90 degrees.

Download

```
compile 'rongi.rotate-layout:rotate-layout:3.0.0'
```

Features

Handles all touch events in a correct way. You press the same button you touch!
Layout measures itself in a correct way. This means that if the original view is 50x100, then 90 degrees rotated it will measure itself as 100x50 and can fit in another layout with this dimensions.

[RotateLayout Link](https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout)

Comment: Thanks that worked. I had to set ```layout_height="fill_parent"``` (which becomes the width after the 90 degree rotation) of the ```RotateLayout```.